# Ruby on Rails Update Record based on Checkbox Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-update

I have a Ruby on Rails form that allows users to update a table called "Transfers".  What I want to do is if the user has selected a particular checkbox in the form (no_from_dept_yn), I want it to always set 3 other fields to default values, regardless of what the user may have chosen.  The commented out section below is where I had attempted to do this, but could not figure out the proper syntax for updating.  This does work when used in the create method. This is what I have in the transfers controller.

```
def update
    @transfer = transfer.find(params[:id])
    # if @transfer.no_from_dept_yn == true
    #  @transfer.from_person = 'Default User'
    #  @transfer.department = 'Default Dept'
    #  @transfer.location = ''
    # end
    respond_to do |format|
    if @transfer.update_attributes(params[:transfer])
    format.html { redirect_to @transfer, notice: 'Transfer was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      @locations = Location.order(:name)
      @users = User.order("last_name, first_name, middle_name")
      @depts = Department.order("department_id")
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @transfer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: IIRC checkbox parameter values don't hit the server as booleans. Check your logs to see the format of the checkbox value in the params then modify your conditional accordingly.

Comment: It looks like the database value is a tinyint, but I neglected to mention that this way of doing it does work in the create method...same exact if statement.  I would think that as long as it's 0 it would think it's false, otherwise would return true (with RoR I'm not sure).

Answer (score 0):

If no_from_dept_yn is a column in the transfers table you'll want to simply make it like this:

```
if @transfer.no_from_dept_yn?
...
```

If it's not then you'll need to check the param separately.  Let me know if that's the case and I'll update the answer for you.

Comment: It is in the database table, but that did not work....not sure why.  It continues to put whatever is in the actual input boxes.  How would I check the param separately, just so I can give that a try?

Comment: `logger.info("@transfer.no_from_dept_yn: #{@transfer.no_from_dept_yn}")` will show you what the value of that is, you should be able to go from there.